# Tengo un problema con la petición POST en express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, post

Resulta que tengo un servidor express con nodejs, donde hago una petición POST, la petición se realiza, pero luego, estando en la página que se carga cuando hago la petición, si la quiero recargar, me sale un cartel que me pregunta si quiero volver a reenviar la petición, cuando solo quiero recargar la página y ya está.

Este es mi servidor:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var index = require('./routes/index');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);


//Autentication with instagram configuration


module.exports = app;
```

Este es el index donde yo envío el formulario para que haga la petición:

```
extends layout
block content
    .view.hm-black-light(data-slides='["images/1.jpg","images/2.jpg","images/3.jpg",]')
        .full-bg-img.flex-center
            ul.animated.fadeInDown
                li
                    h1.display-3.b-4.font-bold
                        b.black-text Grapict
                li
                    h3.mb-5 
                        b.white-text See the posts you really want to see
                li
                    button.btn.btn-black.hoverable(type='button', data-toggle='modal', data-target='#register')
                        i.fab.fa-instagram.fa-lg
                        |  Login

    #register.modal.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel', aria-hidden='true')
        .modal-dialog(role='document')
            .modal-content
                .modal-header
                    h5#exampleModalLabel.modal-title.h5.text-center.mb-1 Sign up with Instagram
                    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-label='Close')
                        span(aria-hidden='true') ×
                .modal-body
                    form.container(method='post', action='/home')
                        .row
                            .col-md-10
                                .md-form
                                    i.fa.fa-envelope.prefix.black-text
                                    input.form-control(type='text', id='defaultForm-email')
                                    label(for='defaultForm-email') Email
                                .md-form
                                    i.fa.fa-lock.prefix.black-text
                                    input.form-control(type='password', id='defaultForm-pass')
                                    label(for='defaultForm-pass') Password
                                .text-center
                                    button.btn.btn-outline-black.hoverable(type='submit') Log in

    script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', integrity='sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl', crossorigin='anonymous')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.5/js/mdb.min.js')
    script(src='js/main.js')
```

y esta es la página a la que se me redirecciona:

```
extends layout
block content
    h1 Welcome to Grapict
```

¿Qué hago mal?

Comment: Recargar una página que se rendereó via POST implica reenviar la petición POST. Mejor en tu ruta que recibe el post procesa los datos y redirígelo a otra url (o a la misma), eso hará que en realidad aterrice en una página rendereada luego de una petición GET

Answer (score 1):

Extendiendo mi comentario:

Al recibir una petición POST, en respuesta no renderees HTML, sino que redirígelo a una ruta que haga el render:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

   ...haces algo con los datos de req...

   res.redirect('/login_exitoso');
});
```

Esa respuesta debiese dar un header 302.

Sin embargo, según la [especificación HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), puede que un browser en particular al seguir la url de un header 302, mantenga el método (No me ha tocado verlo, así que no me consta) y para eso existe el header 303 que obliga a cargar la URL de redirección con una petición GET:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

   ...haces algo con los datos de req...

   res.redirect(303, '/login_exitoso');
});
```

Comment: Wow! Que interesante, gracias por compartir.

Comment: justo andaba con un problema parecido, pero ya estaba haciendo el redirect, y como dices en tu comentario, la peticion mantenia el method y apenas lo cambie se soluciono, lo raro es que solo me pasaba en algunas peticiones